# Comparing two RegEx objects in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, ocr, node-red

I'm using NodeRED to perform some logic on a string which has been created from image analysis (OCR) on Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services.  The image analysis doesn't allow for any pattern matching / input pattern.

The resulting string (let's call it 'A') sometimes interprets characters slightly incorrectly, typical things like 'l' = '1' or 's' = '5'.

The resulting string can be one of only a few different formats, for argument sake lets say:

1. [a-z]{4,5}
2. [a-g]{3}[0-9]{1,2}
3. [0-9][a-z]{4}

What I need to do is determine which format the intepretted string ('A') most closely aligns to ('1', '2' or '3').  Once I establish this, I was planning to adjust the misinterpretted characters and hopefully be left with a string that is (near) perfect.

My initial plan was to convert 'A' into RegEx - so if 'A' came back as "12345", I would change this to a RegEx object [1|l][2|z]34[5|s], compare this object to the RegEx objects and hopefully one would come back as a match.

In reality, the interpretted string is more like 8 alphanumeric and five different (fairly complex) RegEx possibilities, but I've tried to simplify the problem for the purposes of this question.

So the question: is it possible to compare RegEx in this way?  Does anyone have any other suggestions on how this image analysis could be improved?

Thanks

Comment: I'd guess your best bet for comparing regex would be to call `toString()` and then compare the strings.

Comment: Do you mean convert the 3 x RegEx possibilities (in my example) into strings and compare those with the string version of RegEx of 'A'?  How would I go about comparing those?

Comment: *"most closely aligns to"*: that will involve processing. There is no out of the box solution.

Comment: I would build a Cartesian product, and compare those to your expected patterns. In your example `12345`, the Cartesian product is `12345`, `l2345`, `1z345`, `lz345`, `1234s`, `l234s`, `1z34s`, `lz34s`.

Comment: That's great, thanks @PeterThoeny, hadn't realised it went by that name but managed to find a script to help - 'f=([a,...b],o=[])=>a?a.flatMap(x=>f(b,[...o,x])):[o]'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a Cartesian product to compare a string for possible matches. Test string is `'abclz'`, which could match `pattern1` or `pattern2`:

```js
const cartesian = (...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));
const charMapping = {
  '1': ['1','l'],
  'l': ['1','l'],
  '2': ['2','z'],
  'z': ['2','z'],
  '5': ['5','s'],
  's': ['5','s']
};
const buckets = {
  pattern1: /^[a-z]{4,5}$/,
  pattern2: /^[a-g]{3}[0-9]{1,2}$/,
  pattern3: /^[0-9][a-z]{4}$/
};

const input = 'abclz';
console.log('input:', input);
let params = input.split('').map(c => charMapping[c] || [c]);
let toCompare = cartesian(...params).map(arr => arr.join(''));
console.log('toCompare:', toCompare);
let potentialMatches = toCompare.flatMap(str => {
  return Object.keys(buckets).map(pattern => {
    let match = buckets[pattern].test(str);
    console.log(str, pattern + ':', match);
    return match ? str : null;
  }).filter(Boolean);
});
console.log('potentialMatches:', potentialMatches);
```

Output:

```
input: abclz
toCompare: [
  "abc12",
  "abc1z",
  "abcl2",
  "abclz"
]
abc12 pattern1: false
abc12 pattern2: true
abc12 pattern3: false
abc1z pattern1: false
abc1z pattern2: false
abc1z pattern3: false
abcl2 pattern1: false
abcl2 pattern2: false
abcl2 pattern3: false
abclz pattern1: true
abclz pattern2: false
abclz pattern3: false
potentialMatches: [
  "abc12",
  "abclz"
]
```